# django-tastypie try to create related objects on POST request

Tags: django, api, backbone.js, tastypie

When I try to create an object with a foreignkey (2 in this case) through my project API, tastypie try to create the related objects as well (order & participant here):

```
class ParticipationResource(ModelResource):
    order = fields.ForeignKey(Order, 'order', full=True,)
    participant = fields.ForeignKey(UserProfile, 'participant', full=True)

    class Meta:
        authorization = Authorization()
        queryset = Participation.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'participation'
        fields = ['id', 'order', 'participant', 'products', 'created_at', 'modified_at']
        filtering = {
            'participant': ALL
        }
        detail_allowed_methods = ['get', 'post', 'put', 'delete',]
        always_return_data = True
```

Data posted:

```
 {
     "order": {
         "id":"1", 
         "resource_uri":"/api/v1/order/1/"
         ...
      },
     "participant":{
         "id":"1",
         "resource_uri":"/api/v1/participant/1/"
         ...
      },
     "products":[]
  }
```

Error message (network_id is a foreign key on the user profile model) :

```
"error_message": "app_user_profile.network_id may not be NULL",
```

As you can see I'm sending the full objects in my POST request, I tried with only the resource_uri and it worked fine, the problem is that I need the full objects for client side rendering (I'm using Backbone and the model is automatically rendered). So how can I do ? Is there a way to tell tastypie to not create the related objects ?

Comment: What you're asking is how to have Tastypie return full nested objects, but when you POST back, have Backbone only POST the resource_uri, not the full JSON for the nested objects?

Are you using Backbone-Tastypie or Backbone-Relational to handle the nested objects on the Backbone side of things?  Or, so you have a custom parse() function?

Comment: I want to use only full objects to be able to render automatically nested objects on Backbone's side but it seems Tastypie is unable to handle the related objects and try to create new ones when we don't give the resource_uri (though the resource_uri is inside the object). I use Backbone-Tastypie and custom parse() function.

Comment: You have a little typo, fields(.)ForeignKey

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you configure TastyPie for full=True, it works both ways - it returns full nested objects, but also accepts full nested objects.

What you need to do is configure Backbone to not SEND the full JSON of the nested objects, but  just the resource_uri.

There's a couple ways to do this - one way is to just use [Backbone-Relational](https://github.com/PaulUithol/Backbone-relational) which takes care of the parsing and creation of nested models - so you don't have to do a custom parse().

Another is to use [Backbone-Tastypie](https://github.com/PaulUithol/backbone-tastypie) (by the same author) which is a subset of the Backbone-Relational code that makes it easier to work with TastyPie.

But, if you want to stick with what you have, you need to write a custom toJSON function that simply returns the resource_uri instead of a nested object.

This keeps the Backbone Models intact, but when their serialized to be sent to the server, only the resource uri is used:

```
 {
     "order": "/api/v1/order/1/",
     "participant":"/api/v1/participant/1/",
     "products":[]
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried to extract the resource_uri on Tastypie's side but didn't think about change the way it works in Backbone. I'll give a try to Backbone-Relational first and try to write a custom toJSON function if I can't get what I want...

Comment: I moved to django-piston for unrelated reasons so I don't have this issue anymore but I've adopted Backbone-Relational (which is really helpful) and I think it would have done the trick. Thanks again.